# In Visual Studio Code, why is the digit '7' is highlighted differently than other integers? And how can I change it?

Tags: vb.net, macos, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

- MacOS: 10.13.6
- VSCode: 1.41.1
- Language: Visual Basic

The number **`7`** is highlighted differently.  When used in functions, arrays, or other places as a literal, it is the color of a variable instead of matching the other integers.  This only happens when the digit is preceded by a space.

[image: Seven is a special snowflake.]

I'm wondering why this is, and where it's defined.  I'd like to make a change in the syntax file that will correct it, but I don't know where to look, or what to change once I get there.

I know this is more a question about a configuration file for an application rather than a coding question, but I'm hoping it's appropriate here.  Please advise if otherwise.

Comment: it happens to any whole number that starts with a 7 and a space in front, any float is highlighted correct

Comment: whole number that starts with a 7 and a space in front are recognized as `variable.other.asp` the other numbers are `constant.numeric.asp`

Comment: @rioV8 I don't use VS Code, but this is very interesting. I installed it just to replicate the above code and was surprised to see the same thing happen on my machine. Can you elaborate? Is this a bug or what?

Comment: @djv I'm just supporting that the error should be in the Textmate grammer files because  certain numbers get classified very differently, the scope viewer shows that the space is important to get the variable classification. Try to find the specific TM file for Visual Basic.

Comment: @djv Found the typo in the Textmate grammer file for VB

Comment: See my answer for a fix of the error, you can make a bug report for this.

Answer (score 6):

Problem is in the file
`vscode/extensions/vb/syntaxes/asp-vb-net.tmlanguage.json`

They have not added a few critical back slashes.

Search and replace the following

`_x7f-xff` and replace with `_\\x7f-\\xff`

There is also something called a `support.function.asp` that was allowed to begin with a `7`.

**Example**

This was part of the regex to recognize a variable name

`\\s*\\b([a-zA-Z_x7f-xff][a-zA-Z0-9_x7f-xff]*?)\\b\\s*`

This means that anything that starts with `7` is a variable.

There is also a rule that matches `$7` as a variable.